# How can I split a string to obtain a filename?

Tags: c#

I am trying to split the string. Here is the string.

```
string fileName =   "description/ask_question_file_10.htm"
```

I have to remove "description/" and ".htm" from this string. So the result I am looking for "ask_question_file_10". I have to look for "/" and ".htm" I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the [Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx):

```
string fileName = "description/ask_question_file_10.htm";

string result = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
// result == "ask_question_file_10"
```

Answer (score 5):

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("description/ask_question_file_10.htm")
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
string myResult = fileName.SubString (fileName.IndexOf ("/") + 1);
if ( myResult.EndsWith (".htm" ) )
   myResult = myResult.SubString (0, myResult.Length - 4);
```

IF it is really a path then you can use

```
string myResult = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
```

EDIT - relevant links:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hxthx5h6.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2333wewz.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.length.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
 string fileName = "description/ask_question_file_10.htm";
 string name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName);
```